# Resume my application on coming back from google maps

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, android-activity

i want to show one location in google map, for that i used the below code:

```
    String geo = maindata.getString("map");
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, geo, "", "");
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    try {
       cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent1);
}
     });
   }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The google map application is getting launched and it is showing proper location also,
BUT the problem is, when press back button then it is restarting my application.

whereas i want to resume from the lunching position

Answer (score 1):

You can display particular location on google map  by using following code snippet:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lattitude+ ","
                            + longitude+ "+&mode=d");
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                    if (isAppInstalled("com.google.android.apps.maps")) {

                        mapIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                                "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                    }
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Here latitude and longitude belongs the location which you want to display on map.

```
 /**
 * helper function to check if Maps is installed
 **/


 private boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = mActivity.getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
```

And on back press from google map user will redirect to the same activity from which google map was launched.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your activity to the buttom of the stack and then launch the Google map app activity

do the following :

```
        String geo = maindata.getString("map");
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, geo, "", "");
final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
try {
     TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class); //Instead Of MainActivity you can add your Launching activity Name
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);
   cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
    startActivity(intent1);
 }
      });
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```